# What is $l^2(\mathbb{Z}^2)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-analysis

From a textbook in *Harmonic Analysis*:

> [image]

What is meant by the term "$l^2(\mathbb{Z}^2)$", and how is it different from $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers, while $\mathbb{Z^2}$ is the set $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$.  Note that the transformation yields a double indexed wavelet coefficients.

Comment: It's not that different from $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$. It's just the functions $f:\mathbb{Z}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^2} |f(n)|^2<\infty$.

Comment: If  you have a function $f\in L^2(S^1\times S^1)$, then it's Fourier coefficients will be in $l^2(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ rather than $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $l^2(\Bbb Z^2)$ is the set of square-summable families of complex numbers $\{u_{m,n}\}_{(m,n)\in\Bbb Z^2}$.

By square-summable we mean $$\sum |u_{m,n}|^2<\infty$$

It is endowed with an inner product the same way as $l^2(\Bbb Z)$ which makes it a separable Hilbert space (the proof is identical to the $\Bbb Z$ case).

Fact: there is only one separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, up to isomorphism, so $l^2(\Bbb Z^2)$ has to be isomorphic to $l^2(\Bbb Z)$. One way to think about this is the following:

> Theorem:
>
> Let $\{u_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a sequence of **non-negative** real numbers
>   indexed by a **countable** set $I$. Then the non-decreasing sequence
>   $$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N u_{\varphi(n)}$$ has the same limit (hence denoted
>   by $\sum_{i\in I}u_i $) for all bijections $\varphi:\Bbb N\to I$.

In other words, the order in which you add the elements does not affect the status of convergence of the series, or its sum.

Therefore, since $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z^2$ are both countable, any bijection between them will induce an isomorphism between $l^2(\Bbb Z)$ and $l^2(\Bbb Z^2)$.

In some cases, however, it may seem more natural to consider one notation rather than the other. But both are really simply spaces of countable sequences whose square is an absolutely convergent series.

Comment: The OP asked, simply, what is $l^2(\Bbb Z^2)$, and how is it different from $l^2(\Bbb Z)$? How does this answer address that?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I explain why they are isomorphic although they have different presentations. I could add the definition, though, you're right.

Comment: Well, I read your answer, and I’m still confused ‍♂️

Comment: I appreciate your edit 

Comment: You're welcome :)